# How to find hierarchical tree last nodes c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find last items of hierarchical tree.

```
class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
    var list = new List<Node> {
        new Node {Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "N 1"},
        new Node {Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "N 1.1"},
        new Node {Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "N 1.2"},
        new Node {Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "N 1.1.1"},
        new Node {Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Name = "N 1.1.2"},
        new Node {Id = 6, ParentId = 2, Name = "N 1.1.3"}
    };
```

is this possible with c# or linq query?

Comment: Of course, what have you tried already?

Comment: Try to find out with Id isn't used as ParentId

Answer (score 3):

Last nodes are those which are not other nodes parent.

Use this query:

```
var q = list.Where(x => list.All(y => y.ParentId != x.Id));
```

Comment: Could also have used in the inner condition `list.Count(y => y.ParentId == x.Id) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
var hasChild = list.Select(n => n.ParentId); 
var lastNodes = list.Where(n => !hasChild.Contain(n.Id));
```